How do install gst-python on macOS to work with the recommended GStreamer installers?
I'm trying to get the following to work on macOS 14.4.1 on an M1 Pro:
$ python3
Python 3.12.2 (main, Feb  6 2024, 20:19:44) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import gi
>>> gi.require_version('GLib', '2.0')
>>> gi.require_version('GObject', '2.0')
>>> gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 126, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Gst not available

Note:
$ which python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3

I found this question: Installing gst-python in macOS. It appears I need to install gst-python. I've already installed the 1.24 runtime and development installers of GStreamer--I opted not to use Homebrew after reading the notes there--but apparently gst-python is not installed with it.
In the StackOverflow question @chronosynclastic describes cloning the gstreamer GitLab repository and then building the gst-python subproject, so I tried the same:
$ meson setup builddir -Dpygi-overrides-dir=/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gi/overrides && ninja -C builddir
The Meson build system
Version: 1.4.0
Source dir: /Users/dspitzer/dev/from_gitlab/gstreamer/subprojects/gst-python
Build dir: /Users/dspitzer/dev/from_gitlab/gstreamer/subprojects/gst-python/builddir
Build type: native build
Project name: gst-python
Project version: 1.24.1.1
C compiler for the host machine: cc (clang 15.0.0 "Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)")
C linker for the host machine: cc ld64 1053.12
Host machine cpu family: aarch64
Host machine cpu: aarch64
Found pkg-config: YES (/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/bin/pkg-config) 0.29.2
Run-time dependency gstreamer-1.0 found: YES 1.24.1
Run-time dependency gstreamer-base-1.0 found: YES 1.24.1
Run-time dependency gmodule-no-export-2.0 found: YES 2.74.4
Library dl found: YES
Found CMake: /opt/homebrew/bin/cmake (3.29.1)
Run-time dependency pygobject-3.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig, framework and cmake)
Looking for a fallback subproject for the dependency pygobject-3.0

meson.build:26:16: ERROR: Neither a subproject directory nor a pygobject.wrap file was found.

A full log can be found at /Users/dspitzer/dev/from_gitlab/gstreamer/subprojects/gst-python/builddir/meson-logs/meson-log.txt

But I can't figure out how to fix "Run-time dependency pygobject-3.0 found: NO".
Note: l'L'l's comment pointed out that the pip3 command below is using a different version of Python. I fixed  that--so you can skip to "Update" below.
I found this StackOverflow answer (and comment) and successfully ran brew install pygobject3 gtk+3 but:
$ pip3 install pygobject
Collecting pygobject
  Using cached pygobject-3.48.1.tar.gz (714 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      + meson setup /private/var/folders/sb/329vdstd77q73c_7j_smp9r40000gp/T/pip-install-thqb1k2v/pygobject_ad81b1b46af0427a953b312d45c6e129 /private/var/folders/sb/329vdstd77q73c_7j_smp9r40000gp/T/pip-install-thqb1k2v/pygobject_ad81b1b46af0427a953b312d45c6e129/.mesonpy-aial33lr -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md -Dtests=false -Dwheel=true --wrap-mode=nofallback --native-file=/private/var/folders/sb/329vdstd77q73c_7j_smp9r40000gp/T/pip-install-thqb1k2v/pygobject_ad81b1b46af0427a953b312d45c6e129/.mesonpy-aial33lr/meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.4.0
      Source dir: /private/var/folders/sb/329vdstd77q73c_7j_smp9r40000gp/T/pip-install-thqb1k2v/pygobject_ad81b1b46af0427a953b312d45c6e129
      Build dir: /private/var/folders/sb/329vdstd77q73c_7j_smp9r40000gp/T/pip-install-thqb1k2v/pygobject_ad81b1b46af0427a953b312d45c6e129/.mesonpy-aial33lr
      Build type: native build
      Project name: pygobject
      Project version: 3.48.1
      C compiler for the host machine: cc (clang 15.0.0 "Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)")
      C linker for the host machine: cc ld64 1053.12
      Host machine cpu family: aarch64
      Host machine cpu: aarch64
      Program python3 found: YES (/Users/dspitzer/.new_local/share/pyenv/versions/3.11.7/bin/python3.11)
      Found pkg-config: YES (/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Commands/pkg-config) 0.29.2
      Run-time dependency python found: YES 3.11
      Found CMake: /opt/homebrew/bin/cmake (3.29.1)
      Run-time dependency gobject-introspection-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig, framework and cmake)
      Not looking for a fallback subproject for the dependency gobject-introspection-1.0 because:
      Use of fallback dependencies is disabled.

      ../meson.build:29:9: ERROR: Dependency 'gobject-introspection-1.0' is required but not found.

      A full log can be found at /private/var/folders/sb/329vdstd77q73c_7j_smp9r40000gp/T/pip-install-thqb1k2v/pygobject_ad81b1b46af0427a953b312d45c6e129/.mesonpy-aial33lr/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Update: I had added $HOME/.new_local/bin (created by the GStreamer install) to my PATH, in front of /opt/homebrew/bin so pip3 was running the one in the former which resulted in a different version of Python.
So I fixed the path and reran:
$ pip3 install pygobject
Collecting pygobject
  Downloading pygobject-3.48.2.tar.gz (715 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 715.2/715.2 kB 13.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      + meson setup /private/var/folders/sb/329vdstd77q73c_7j_smp9r40000gp/T/pip-install-i7tjs1ue/pygobject_d272551047184d069c19b9453f89f97d /private/var/folders/sb/329vdstd77q73c_7j_smp9r40000gp/T/pip-install-i7tjs1ue/pygobject_d272551047184d069c19b9453f89f97d/.mesonpy-rhycpxqs -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md -Dtests=false -Dwheel=true --wrap-mode=nofallback --native-file=/private/var/folders/sb/329vdstd77q73c_7j_smp9r40000gp/T/pip-install-i7tjs1ue/pygobject_d272551047184d069c19b9453f89f97d/.mesonpy-rhycpxqs/meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.4.0
      Source dir: /private/var/folders/sb/329vdstd77q73c_7j_smp9r40000gp/T/pip-install-i7tjs1ue/pygobject_d272551047184d069c19b9453f89f97d
      Build dir: /private/var/folders/sb/329vdstd77q73c_7j_smp9r40000gp/T/pip-install-i7tjs1ue/pygobject_d272551047184d069c19b9453f89f97d/.mesonpy-rhycpxqs
      Build type: native build
      Project name: pygobject
      Project version: 3.48.2
      C compiler for the host machine: cc (clang 15.0.0 "Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)")
      C linker for the host machine: cc ld64 1053.12
      Host machine cpu family: aarch64
      Host machine cpu: aarch64
      Program python3 found: YES (/Users/dspitzer/dev/python/dashboard-fake-frontend/env/bin/python3.12)
      Found pkg-config: YES (/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/bin/pkg-config) 0.29.2
      Run-time dependency python found: YES 3.12
      Found CMake: /opt/homebrew/bin/cmake (3.29.1)
      Run-time dependency gobject-introspection-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig, framework and cmake)
      Not looking for a fallback subproject for the dependency gobject-introspection-1.0 because:
      Use of fallback dependencies is disabled.

      ../meson.build:29:9: ERROR: Dependency 'gobject-introspection-1.0' is required but not found.

      A full log can be found at /private/var/folders/sb/329vdstd77q73c_7j_smp9r40000gp/T/pip-install-i7tjs1ue/pygobject_d272551047184d069c19b9453f89f97d/.mesonpy-rhycpxqs/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

So the Python version wasn't the issue.
Now I'm stuck here.

It appears you are using two versions of Python (3.11 & 3.12), so maybe that's the issue?

I found this answer to a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72600498/4766.
I installed Miniconda and then ran:
conda create --name conda_env python=3.12.2
conda init zsh
conda activate conda_env
conda install -c conda-forge pygobject
conda install gtk3
conda install gstreamer

And now this works:
$ python3
Python 3.12.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Feb 16 2024, 20:54:21) [Clang 16.0.6 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import gi
>>> gi.require_version('GLib', '2.0')
>>> gi.require_version('GObject', '2.0')
>>> gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
>>>


Do you think conda would be fair to use for a production app? I haven't really used conda for years because it seemed to get in the way before it provided anything useful to me. I haven't used it since 2017 IIRC. What's your use case, Daryl? These might be interesting: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/lcqjxq/does_anybody_use_conda_in_production/ and https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17608639

My use case was just to hack together a prototype on macOS by any means necessary. This will not turn into a product.

The error
ERROR: Dependency 'gobject-introspection-1.0' is required but not found.

Meson can't find it, because pkg-config and Cmake can't find it. Ensure it is installed and environment variables are set correctly.
Solution
Since pygobject3 will install gobject-introspection-1.0 as a dependency (see https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/b1c4dff59a2e1b03bf86532d7424bf1a11384b0d/Formula/p/pygobject3.rb#L28)
depends_on "gobject-introspection"

The problem for you might be that gobject-introspection is installed but pkg-config can't find it. Mine is in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gobject-introspection, so I need to add the folder containing the pc to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gobject-introspection/1.82.0/lib/pkgconfig. I do it with:
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gobject-introspection/1.82.0/lib/pkgconfig"

Just in case you've messed around with gobject-introspection, run brew reinstall gobject-introspection to make sure the files are there.
Test it works
Confirm it's available with pkg-config --modversion gobject-introspection-1.0
Successful
$ pkg-config --modversion gobject-introspection-1.0
1.82.0

Unsuccessful
$ pkg-config --modversion gobject-introspection-1.0
Package gobject-introspection-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gobject-introspection-1.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gobject-introspection' found

Bonus
What does this .pc ("pkg config") file look like? It's metadata that allows you to use pkg-config for compiling/linking. Here's what gobject-introspection-1.0.pc looks like:
prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gobject-introspection/1.82.0
bindir=${prefix}/bin
datadir=${prefix}/share
includedir=${prefix}/include
libdir=${prefix}/lib

g_ir_scanner=${bindir}/g-ir-scanner
g_ir_compiler=${bindir}/g-ir-compiler
g_ir_generate=${bindir}/g-ir-generate
gidatadir=${datadir}/gobject-introspection-1.0
girdir=${datadir}/gir-1.0
typelibdir=${libdir}/girepository-1.0

Name: gobject-introspection
Description: GObject Introspection
Version: 1.82.0
Requires: glib-2.0 >= 2.82.0, gobject-2.0 >= 2.82.0
Libs: -L${libdir} -lgirepository-1.0
Cflags: -I${includedir}/gobject-introspection-1.0

